# Using lxml and etree to get nested elements

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm using LibXML etree to parse one XML file and write elements of it to a new file. For the most part I've been able to get single elements by specifying points in the tree but I've come across a problem when trying to capture a node and all its children/grandchildren.

The input node looks like this:

```
            <abstract>
                <p>
                    Some explanation text
                </p>
                <p>
                    Some more explanation text 
                    <italic>
                        Title for link 
                    </italic>some brief description, visit 
                    <uri xlink:href="https://example.com">
                        https://example.com
                    </uri> 
                </p>
            </abstract>
```

And I get the following:

```
          <abstract>
            <p>
             Some explanation text.
             </p>
            <p>
             Some more explanation text 
             </p>
            <italic>
              Title for link
            </italic>
            <uri>
               https://example.com
            </uri>
          </abstract>
```

What I'm after is an exact replica of the input (including, if possible, the namespace). In my Python conversion script, I have the following:

```
# abstract
if tree.find(".//abstract") != None:
       abstract = etree.SubElement(mods,'abstract')
       abs_list = tree.xpath(".//abstract/descendant::*")
       for para in abs_list:
          ab_p = etree.SubElement(abstract,para.tag)
          ab_p.text = para.text
```

**UPDATE 2022-06-16**

I'm now able to get the structure:

```
                <p>
                    Some explanation text
                </p>
                <p>
                    Some more explanation text 
                    <italic>
                        Title for link 
                    </italic>some brief description, visit 
                    <uri>
                        https://example.com
                    </uri> 
                </p>
            </abstract>
```

But I haven't been able to get the namespace and my code is limited in that it assumes that:

1. all direct children of the `<abstract>` tag are `<p>` tags
2. every other tag belongs to the previous `<p>` tag

The code I now have is:

```
if tree.find(".//abstract") != None:
       abstract = etree.SubElement(mods,'abstract')
       abs_elem = tree.xpath(".//abstract/descendant::*")
       for para in abs_elem:
              if para.tag == "p":
                     p = etree.SubElement(abstract,'p')  
                     p.text = para.text
              else:
                   ab_p = etree.SubElement(p,para.tag)
                   ab_p.text = para.text
```

Whilst this should be sufficient for most use cases, it's not very refined and if there is a document where one (or both) of the 2 assumptions above are not met, then this will fail.

Any suggestions on how I can rewrite this to nullify the reliance on those 2 assumptions?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. The code is incomplete. What is `mods`, for example? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mzjn - thanks for taking a look. In this case `mods` is irrelevant since this is just the parent tag that the `abstract` is added to. Essentially, all I'm doing is copying a node from one XML file to another. Sometimes I need to alter the attributes, text, tags or add namespaces which is why I'm not copying them.

Comment: If `mods` is irrelevant, don't include it in the question. Sorry to nag, but please read [mcve].

Comment: There is no namespace in your XML input sample, so I don't know how to help with that.